# Difference between two electrostatic problems involving dielectric

Tags: electrostatics, dielectric

Suppose i imerse a charge $q$ on a spherical dielectric $(\epsilon_R)$ (linear). I put such a charge at the origin, and i want to know the displacement vector, the electric field, etc inside the sphere.

The answer is pretty trivial: $\vec D = \frac{q}{4 \pi r^2}\hat r, \vec E = \vec D/\epsilon$.

Now, my question is, suppose another problem, essentially similar, but instead of a charge $q$ at the origin, we insert a dipole $\vec p$ at the origin. Now, to solve this problem, we can not just say that $\vec D = \frac{3 \vec r(\vec r \vec p ) - \vec p r^2}{4 \pi r^5}$. Why? That is, at the first problem we could easily manipulate the formulas we already know to get the fields equation. But, for the dipole, we will need to solve the Poisson equation analytically (Get the solution with cylindrical symmetry etc).

What have changed? why i can not just goes just as i did with the point charge?

Answer (score 0):

If the material is linear and isotropic, then the formula you give for the dipole is correct. You'll obtain it from solving Poisson's equation. I don't understand the question tbh.

Edit: If you know that
$$
\Delta \phi = f
$$
then you know that
$$
\Delta \left(\frac{\phi}{\varepsilon}\right) = \frac{f}{\varepsilon}
$$
for $\varepsilon=$const. No matter if $f$ comes from a point charge, a dipole or any other charge distribution.